# Invoke Lex Bot in Custom State from Amazon Connect

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have a lex bot with multiple intents that gets invoked from Connect. If I know exactly why the caller is calling, is it possible for me to invoke the bot but start off eliciting a slot from a particular intent? Maybe if I could programatically invoke the bot from a lambda in an ElicitSlot state?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Connect gives you two options for calling Lex you may want to explore further:
 1. you can specify a subset of intents in the block that's calling Lex, so if your Connect flow already knows which intent needs to be called, then just specify that single intent.
 2. You can set session attributes in Amazon Connect that get passed to Lex. So you can put any context information there and have your Lex logic (implemented as Lambda validation function) make choices as to what to do next based on that information. This may not work for picking intents, but can be used for picking the right slot to fill next.